# Making an Angular Directive / Component (ng1 and ng2) require a specific parent Directive / Component

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-directives, angular9

Let's pretend I wanted to build a general purpose FAQ component. Let's also pretend I wanted the structure to be like this

```
<faq-group title="Things">
   <faq question="Question 1?">Answer 1</faq>
   <faq question="Question 2?">Answer 2</faq>
</faq-group>
```

What I want to simply prevent, is for lone `<faq>` components to exist outside of the `<faq-group>`. I don't want Angular to bootstrap a faq component at all unless it is under a faqGroup. It could throw an error perhaps, that'd work too.

I was wondering if this is at all possible with ng1 Directives and ng2 Components.  I'm not interested in ng1 Controllers, what I want is to build up a component library that doesn't depend on a controller being present.

This is my component as it is. Right now, the only real use of the faqGroup directive is mostly for styling purposes, but angularjs will absolutely attempt to just bootstrap and render each lonely faq element it finds regardless of where.  I'm just looking to dictate the structure a little bit.  You know like how `<td>` isn't really valid outside of a `<tr>` and a `<tr>` isn't really valid outside of a `<table>`.

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app')
.directive('faqGroup', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: `<div ng-transclude></div>`
    }
}])
.directive('faq', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { question: '@' },
        template: `
            <div class="question" ng-class="{exposed: expose}" ng-click="expose = !expose">{{ question }} <i class="fas" ng-class="{'fa-plus': !expose, 'fa-minus': expose}"></i></div>
            <div class="answer" ng-show="expose" ng-transclude></div>`,
        link: function($scope) {
            $scope.expose = false;
        }
    }
}]);
```